# How to Add Multiple Pin On google Map in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

i have code to add single pin on Google map. And This work Completely.
But When i add second pin, it override with first one.
This is my code to add single pin on map.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude1 longitude:longitude1 zoom:18];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

self.view = mapView_;
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1, longitude1);
marker.title = @"Ahmedabad";
marker.snippet = @"India";
marker.map = mapView_;
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m1.png"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.view = mapView_;     
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{       
   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   marker.animated=YES;
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
   marker.title = @"name";
   marker.snippet = @"snippet";
   marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view = self.googleMapView;     
for(int i=0;i<[markerArray count];i++)
{  
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [markerArray objectAtIndex:i];
   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   marker.animated=YES;
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude,location.longitude);
   marker.title = @"name";
   marker.snippet = @"snippet";
   marker.map = self.googleMapView;
}
```